# php move-uploaded-file is setting the address as the name of the file

Tags: php, html

I have two completely similar codes that one of them works and the other doesnt

```
$id = 1;
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['adminProfilePicture']["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$address = '../img/admin' . $id . 'image.' . $ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['adminProfilePicture']["tmp_name"],$address);
```

this code works perfectly and saves the file in the directory root/img/admin1image.png

```
$id = 1;
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['teamProfilePicture']["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$address = '../img/team' . $id . 'image.' . $ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['teamProfilePicture']["tmp_name"],$address);
```

but this code for some reason sets the address as the name of the file
and saves a file with this name (../img/team1image.png) in the directory root/(../img/team1image.png)

i really dont know what could be wrong
any help would be appreciated
and one other thing is the code works on my localhost
but iam making a project for someone else and this problem occurs on his host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the address

```php
$address = '../img/team' . $id . 'image.' . $ext;
```

to

```php
$address = realpath(__DIR__.'/../img/').'team'.$id.'image.'.$ext;
```

Comment: $address = __DIR__ . '/../img/team'.$id.'image.'.$ext;

Comment: so i changed it to this line of code and it started working